# Apt-offline install; trying to avoid all internet queries

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, offline

We have been testing the use of apt-offline to deal with the issue of updating remote machines without using an internet connection.

This procedure has worked well:
use apt-offline set (--update --install package) and get commands on the online computer, which in the same state as the offline commands, to generate the update.zip file. We then transport the zip to the offline box, run apt-offline install, and then apt-get update and finally apt-get install to install the package on the remote machine.

The only issue that seems to crop up is that as soon as we use the apt-get update and install procedures on the remote boxes, the remote boxes attempt to communicate with the online repositories... they can't, and the install still works, but we were wondering if there was away to eliminate the attempt to connect to the internet on the remote box.

We tried eliminating online sources from /etc/apt/sources.list, but in that case we can't install the packages (since there are no sources for apt-get install to look at. Is there a way to eliminate the internet queries with apt-get install (some way to make it assume that its sources are up to date?) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems I can run apt-get update and apt-get install with the --no-download option and avoid internet queries!